# Intercept click-event on Google Calendar with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-calendar-api

I am trying to do my own stuff when I click on a event in my embedded Google Calendar (`iframe`).
My code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', function (e) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('te-s')) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        }
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.te-s').bind("click", function () {
            alert("test");
        });
</script>
```

`te-s` is the class containing the event-text, and instead of showing this additional details bubble, I (later) want to redirect on my own site (alert is only there for test purposes).
Is this possible using jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure this is possible. I guess your script would have to be within the child iframe to be able to listen to events within it.
Apart from that the class you are referencing 'te-s' will most likely not bear the same name again. These name will keep changing.
The best solution would be to use a call back from the API, if it exists.